# Which collection should i choose in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I need a collection to store a lot of requests from many clients, and at the same time i use one thread processing all the requests stored every five seconds.so which collection should i choose in java to have the best efficiency? obviously, the collection should be thread-safe and efficiency to poll all elements every five seconds,right?

Comment: Might just consider an `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: Polling is generally a bad idea

Answer (score 4):

You may try to use [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) in this case.

> A bounded blocking queue backed by an array. This queue orders
>   elements FIFO (first-in-first-out). The head of the queue is that
>   element that has been on the queue the longest time. The tail of the
>   queue is that element that has been on the queue the shortest time.
>   New elements are inserted at the tail of the queue, and the queue
>   retrieval operations obtain elements at the head of the queue.
>
> This is a classic "bounded buffer", in which a fixed-sized array holds
>   elements inserted by producers and extracted by consumers. Once
>   created, the capacity cannot be changed. Attempts to put an element
>   into a full queue will result in the operation blocking; attempts to
>   take an element from an empty queue will similarly block.

In this there is a **[take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29)** method which will block, without consuming CPU cycles, until an item gets added to the queue. And it is thread safe.

Comment: because of i cant ensure the capacity, i decide to use LinkedBlockingQueue. Any difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a lock-free `DoubleBufferedList` for just this situation. Essentially, you can write to it from multiple threads and the writes will accumulate. When a read comes along the whole list is returned while, at the same time, in a thread-safe way, a new list is created for the writers to write to.

The critical difference between this and any kind of `BlockingQueue` is that with a `Queue` you will need to poll each entry out of it one-at-a-time. This structure gives you the whole accumulated list all at once, containing everything that has accumulated since the last time you looked.

```
public class DoubleBufferedList<T> {
  // Atomic reference so I can atomically swap it through.
  // Mark = true means I am adding to it so momentarily unavailable for iteration.
  private AtomicMarkableReference<List<T>> list = new AtomicMarkableReference<>(newList(), false);

  // Factory method to create a new list - may be best to abstract this.
  protected List<T> newList() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }

  // Get and replace with empty the current list - can return null - does not mean failed.
  public List<T> get() {
    // Atomically grab and replace the list with an empty one.
    List<T> empty = newList();
    List<T> it;
    // Replace an unmarked list with an empty one.
    if (!list.compareAndSet(it = list.getReference(), empty, false, false)) {
      // Failed to replace! 
      // It is probably marked as being appended to but may have been replaced by another thread.
      // Return empty and come back again soon.
      return Collections.<T>emptyList();
    }
    // Successfull replaced an unmarked list with an empty list!
    return it;
  }

  // Grab and lock the list in preparation for append.
  private List<T> grab() {
    List<T> it;
    // We cannot fail so spin on get and mark.
    while (!list.compareAndSet(it = list.getReference(), it, false, true)) {
      // Spin on mark - waiting for another grabber to release (which it must).
    }
    return it;
  }

  // Release the list.
  private void release(List<T> it) {
    // Unmark it - should this be a compareAndSet(it, it, true, false)?
    if (!list.attemptMark(it, false)) {
      // Should never fail because once marked it will not be replaced.
      throw new IllegalMonitorStateException("It changed while we were adding to it!");
    }
  }

  // Add an entry to the list.
  public void add(T entry) {
    List<T> it = grab();
    try {
      // Successfully marked! Add my new entry.
      it.add(entry);
    } finally {
      // Always release after a grab.
      release(it);
    }
  }

  // Add many entries to the list.
  public void add(List<T> entries) {
    List<T> it = grab();
    try {
      // Successfully marked! Add my new entries.
      it.addAll(entries);
    } finally {
      // Always release after a grab.
      release(it);
    }
  }

  // Add a number of entries.
  @SafeVarargs
  public final void add(T... entries) {
    // Make a list of them.
    add(Arrays.<T>asList(entries));
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you compare and contrast this with the ArrayBlockingQueue? I like the approach, since you are filling up the messages and it seems you are minimizing the thread contention. (Not sure if that is the right term). The system does not have to check on every request post if more than one thread has the object. Hmmm... I have to think this through. Can you compare and contrast this to ArrayBlockingQueue. I have a project where config changes every now and then. And I need to reload config and make it available in an atomic fashion. Either all new config or all old, but no middle. I am using an..

Comment: I am using an Atomic reference but might consider using this. But there is a chance two threads could force a load of config at once, this would minimize that to 0. I think. Anyway.. Bookmarked and read to review again when I get to that part in a week or two. :) Thanks!

Comment: @RickHigh - I have added some narrative on the differences with `Queue`s. I would **not** recommend this mechanism for reloadable properties. You are looking for a singleton `HashMap` for that. An `AtomicReference<Map>` would be ideal. This structure is tuned for multiple threads writing with an occasional pick-up of all accumulated.

Comment: I am currently using a AtomicReference<Map> that delivers up a ConcurrentHashMap (internally). The config has many readers, but only one writer. The system essentially waits for a file to change (pointer to a new config dir). If it changes, I reload the config into a new ConcurrentHashMap, and then move it in one go to the AtomicReference. The idea being that you never get 1/2 a config or inconsistent values then I notify via an event that the config changed. The config has to be processes and scored based on environment.

Comment: @RickHigh - Looks like you already have an effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

A static ConcurrentHashmap with timestamp as key and request object as value would be my suggestion.

Comment: Really? What if two requests come in at the same moment? What if the user gets impatient and hits the update button three times or opens up a second browser window. Do you plan to make it synchronized? Why not a ConcurrentHashMap at least?